# How do I get firefox to identify itself as Internet Explorer for certain sites?

Tags: firefox, internet-explorer, firefox-extensions

My bank's website insists that I use `Internet explorer > v7`. I have however disabled internet explorer from windows features and use Firefox instead.

How do I get firefox to identify itself as IE for that particular site?
I'm running windows 7 with firefox 13 right now.